# How does the following example prove that this set of axioms for a probability field is consistent?

Tags: probability-theory, logic

This is froms Kolmogorovs Foundations of probability theory.

He gives the following five axioms.

Let $E $ be a set and $\mathcal F $ be a set of subsets of $E $.
I $\mathcal F $ is closed under finite union and intersection and set diffrence. $\emptyset \in \mathcal F $
II $E \in \mathcal F $
III To each $A \in \mathcal F $ is assigned a nonegative number $P(A) $
IV $P(E)=1 $
V If $A \cap B = \emptyset $ then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$

---

Now it is said that the following example proves that the system of axioms is *consistent*.

Let $E $ consist of the sigle element $\xi $ and let $\mathcal F =\{E,\emptyset \} $, the $P(E)=1 $ and $P(\emptyset ) =0$.

How does this show that no contradictions can be derived from the axioms? Doesn't a set of axioms addmit an unlimited number of interpretations? How does this then show that no one will furnish a contradiction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "example" is a *model* for the axioms, i.e. the "example" provides an interpretation of the five axioms in which they are *true* : you can check it.

Thus, having a model, the *theory* based on the five axioms is *consistent*.

Why ? Assume that we can deduce a contradiction from the axioms : that is, we can deduce from the axioms two "theorems" $\varphi$ and $\lnot \varphi$.

These "theorems", being deduced from the axioms, must be true in every interpretation that satisfy the axioms, i.e. in every *model* of the theory.

But this contradicts our "basic" properties of *truth* : we cannot have a "world" (neither a mathematical one) in which a sentence and its negation are both true.